# Using WMI from PowerShell or C# - how can I get remote host time, including milliseconds?

Tags: c#, powershell, time, wmi, get-wmiobject

I need to get a remote host date & time including milliseconds using WMI.

The following isn't good enough:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UTCTime -ComputerName MY_REMOTE_HOST
```

As milliseconds are NOT implemented in the Win32_CurrentTime class which is derived by the Win32_UTCTime class:

> Milliseconds
>
> Data type: uint32
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Not implemented.
>
> This property is inherited from Win32_CurrentTime.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmitimepprov/win32-currenttime)

I'd appreciate any other suggestions to obtain this information using WMI from either Powershell or C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WMI class win32_operatingsystem contains a property named LocalDateTime which also contains the milliseconds. You need to convert them though.

Simple sample :

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingSystem
$OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LocalDateTime)
```

The output is a DateTime object which also contains the milliseconds.

Comment: This seems to work but I wonder - how is it possible that we extract time from an object that does not appear to have a time field inside? I just ran "Get-WmiObject Win32_operatingsystem  -ComputerName MY_REMOTE_HOST" and the fields returned are:(SystemDirectory,Organization,BuildNumber,RegisteredUser,SerialNumber,Version)

Comment: By default a lot of the WMI objects you request in Powershell show only a subset of the properties (because Powershell has a lot of "templates" built in to filter out the data). By piping the command to fl * (fl is an alias for format-list) you can see them all. Using Get-Member you can also see the properties and datatypes (but you can't see the values).

Answer (score 2):

@bluuf's answer is the one you should use, but as a more complicated alternative, you can get the current date/time from the performance counter WMI classes like this:

```
$perfTime = Get-CimInstance -Query "Select * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor WHERE Name = '0'"
(Get-Date "01/01/1601").AddTicks($perfTimeime.Timestamp_Sys100NS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try PowerShell remoting:

```
$sess = New-PSSession -Credential (Get-Credential)
$dateTime = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock { Get-Date -Format "o" }
```

To enable remoting see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but the solution must be via WMI